# account.checkUsername from telethon not working?

Tags: python, telethon

I am using the code snippet from the documentation of [CheckUsernameRequest](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/account/check_username.html) and it just doesn't work. I tried it with a lot of usernames and channel names . It keeps saying that they don't exist but they DO.

Here are a few I tested :

- https://t.me/lexfridman
- https://t.me/tagliafi

Am I doing something wrong ? Is it broken ?

PS: I don't understand the result type either, it's supposed to be a bool but I find myself dealing with obscure [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.7/library/asyncio-task.html) stuffs.

The code:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.account.CheckUsernameRequest(
        username='lexfridman'
    ))
    if result == True:
        print("yAY")
    else:
        print("pOUAH")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this problem too. Telegram has several [methods](https://core.telegram.org/methods#working-with-usernames) for working with usernames. I guess you need `contacts.ResolveUsernameRequest`. It raises `UsernameNotOccupiedError`, if it can't find the username; otherwise it returns `ResolvedPeer`.

To get it to work properly, you need to use an `async` function:

```py
async def main():
    async with TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        try:
            await client(functions.contacts.ResolveUsernameRequest('lexfridman'))
            print('Found!')
        except UsernameNotOccupiedError as e:
            print('Not found :(')
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. When I launch it, it says "NameError: name 'UsernameNotOccupiedError' is not defined"..

Answer (score 0):

For me, standard methods did not work either. So walk around is using ValueError that is raised if user name is not found.

```
      try:
          user = "safhbkasvjhb"
          await client.get_entity(user)
      except Exception as exception:
          message = (user + type(exception).__name__).replace('\n', " ")
          print(message)
          continue
```

Output:

```
safhbkasvjhb ValueError
```